# Firebase Functions AppCheck keeps failing my device

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-app-check

I have been trying to integrate AppCheck with my Android app, but I can't seem to make a valid request.

As for test purposes, I have been using the following code:

**Android Code**

```
class Application : MultiDexApplication() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)

        val appCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance()
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) appCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(DebugAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance(), true)
        else appCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(SafetyNetAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance(), true)

        super.onCreate()
    }
}

class TestActivity : Activity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val data = "This is a test!"
        Firebase.functions.getHttpsCallable("test").call(data).addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                val result = it.result.data
                print(result)
            }

            else {
                val exception = it.exception
                print(exception)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Function Code**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions")

exports.test = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  if (context.app == undefined) {
    functions.logger.error("Test - Failed validating device integrity!")
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("failed-precondition", "The function must be called from an App Check verified app")
  }

  return data
})
```

I have added the **DebugAppCheckProviderFactory** token to the Firebase console, but no matter what I do, if it is an emulator or physical device, when I call the function, the **failed-precondition** exception is always thrown.

Checking the function logs, I can see that the app is missing:

[image]

I have already read the documentation multiple times and I can't seem to be missing any step. Am I missing something or is there anything I can do to find the root cause for this?

Thank you for your time!

**EDIT:**

As for Martin suggestion, I created a new **OnRequest** function and added the **X-Firebase-AppCheck** header. I received the token correctly and was able to validate it successfully with:

`firebaseAdmin.appCheck().verifyToken(appCheckToken)`

So, my guess is that Android is not adding the **X-Firebase-AppCheck** automatically to the **OnCall** function like it should.

I ran the code and made some breakpoints through the code and noticed the following. The **call** method from Firebase is adding the **Firebase-Instance-ID-Token** but I can't seem to find the **X-Firebase-AppCheck** header anywhere. Maybe I am not supposed to see this value, or maybe I just can't find where it is being added. Or maybe it is not added at all, thus I can't validate my **context.app** at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing everything with no success, in a desperate move, I tried to look to unrelated files and found the solution.

In my **build.gradle** I was importing all the Firebase dependencies with the bom:

```
implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.0.0")
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-functions-ktx"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx"
```

So I thought: "Can the firebase-bom be importing an outdated **functions-ktx** dependency?"

And guess what? As soon as I imported the dependencies without the bom, I started to see the **X-Firebase-AppCheck** being added and the **context.app** being valid.

I ended up with the following **build.gralde**:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx:18.2.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:19.0.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:23.0.3"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-functions-ktx:20.0.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:21.0.1"
```

After a little more investigation, I found out that I was using an outdated **firebase-bom** version. Android Studio used to let me know if there was a new version for the dependencies, but it did not notice me for the **firebase-bom**. Turns out, that I just need to update my **firebase-bom** dependency.

**TL;DR**

Check your Android Firebase libraries version!

Answer (score 1):

It may be required to obtain an `AppCheckToken`:

```
FirebaseAppCheck
        .getInstance()
        .getAppCheckToken(false)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AppCheckToken>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@NonNull AppCheckToken tokenResponse) {

                String appCheckToken = tokenResponse.getToken();
                ...
            }
        });
```

Which has to be passed along, with the HTTP request (the example shows Retrofit, which could also be used instead of `HttpsCallable`:

```
@GET("yourExampleEndpoint")
Call<List<String>> exampleData(
    @Header("X-Firebase-AppCheck") String appCheckToken,
    ...
);
```

Where [`FirebaseFunctions.getInstance().getHttpsCallable().call()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/functions/HttpsCallableReference#call(java.lang.Object)) doesn't tell how or if one has to explicitly set that `X-Firebase-AppCheck` header. Cloud Functions should usually receive an `X-Firebase-AppCheck` header - with the previously retrieved AppCheck token:

```
const appCheckToken = req.header('X-Firebase-AppCheck');

if (!appCheckToken) {
    res.status(401);
    return next('Unauthorized');
}

try {
    const appCheckClaims = await firebaseAdmin.appCheck().verifyToken(appCheckToken);
    // If verifyToken() succeeds, continue with the next middleware function in the stack.
    return next();
} catch (err) {
    res.status(401);
    return next('Unauthorized');
}
```

One can also issue own tokens ...and [checking for `context-app`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/cloud-functions) is also valid.

---

Update: The [Protocol specification for https.onCall](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) reads:

> Optional: `X-Firebase-AppCheck: <token>`
> The Firebase App Check token provided by the client app making the request. The backend automatically verifies this token and decodes it, injecting the appId in the handler's context. If the token cannot be verified, the request is rejected.
> Available for SDK >=3.14.0

To install the minimum required NodeJS dependencies:

```
npm install firebase-functions@">=3.14.0"
npm install firebase-admin@">=9.8.0"
```

---

And last, but not least ...there's even a debug helper for that:

```
dependencies {
    debugImplementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-debug:16.0.0-beta02"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @Martin. I have tried to run the function after a SuccessListener and the result is the same. I can see an "appCheckToken" value, but the context.app is still missing. As for the header, I don't have a req and res values. As I am using the OnCall functions, I have data and context instead. Is there any way to check the headers from these two values?

Comment: This is what is available there: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference ...add LogCat & more Cloud Logging, to see which HTTP headers are actually being sent & received. As it turned out, once can access the headers only within a [HTTP funciton](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events); in case `HttpsCallable` won't attach that `X-Firebase-AppCheck` header somehow, it may be incompatible for the intended use - unless this would provide `context.app` (as headers are being abstracted away).

Comment: Make sure SDK >=3.14.0, there the header should be attached to `HttpsCallable`.

Comment: I have created a new OnRequest and tried to verify the token with firebaseAdmin.appCheck().verifyToken. It seems that it was able to verify the token this way. It seems that my OnCall function is the problem here. I will be double checking the SDK version and will update or comment soon. Thanks a lot for your time @Martin!

Comment: Updated the firebase-functions and firebase-admin but still the same problem in the OnCall function.